# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

I've got an exception with this class: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views".

I know it might be the fact I use async, but I'm a newbie in android dev and I didn't managed to arrange it even reading others cases on Stackoverflow. Help welcome!

My class:

```
 package com.test.example;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;



 public class ShopsActivity extends Activity {


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "mywebserviceurl";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS_STRING = "shop_address";
TextView shop_address;
TextView shop_name;
TextView api;
private ListView list;

private ImageButton button1;
private ImageButton button2;
private ImageButton button3;
private ImageButton button4;


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shops);




        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetJson().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShopsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mise à jour...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                 String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url --->" + url);
                 String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                 String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                 String name = jsonObject.getString("name");    
                 System.out.println("name --->" + name);
                 JSONArray photos_urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos_urls");
                 System.out.println("photos_urls --->" + photos_urls);
                 String address_string = jsonObject.getString("address_string");
                 System.out.println("address_string --->" + address_string);
                 JSONObject booklet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("booklet");
                 String id_booklet = booklet.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id_booklet --->" + id_booklet);
                 String url_booklet = booklet.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url_booklet --->" + url_booklet);
                 String created_at_booklet = booklet.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at_booklet --->" + created_at_booklet);
                 String updated_at_booklet = booklet.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at_booklet --->" + updated_at_booklet);
                 String document_url = booklet.getString("document_url");
                 System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
                 String presented = booklet.getString("presented");
                 System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);


             // Adding value HashMap key => value
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, address_string);
                        oslist.add(map);
                        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopsActivity.this, oslist,
                                R.layout.listview_item_row,
                                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ADDRESS_STRING }, new int[] {
                                        R.id.name_shop, R.id.address_shop});
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        /*  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ShopsActivity.this, ShopActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                            }
                            });*/
                        }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            return null;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();



        }

    }

}
```

And this is my log after trying to use onPostExecute:

```
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1952)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity$GetJson.doInBackground(ShopsActivity.java:141)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity$GetJson.doInBackground(ShopsActivity.java:1)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-30 14:10:28.515: E/AndroidRuntime(12951):    ... 5 more
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951): Activity com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419962f8 that was originally added here
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419962f8 that was originally added here
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity$GetJson.onPreExecute(ShopsActivity.java:77)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at com.begital.votrebijoutier.ShopsActivity.onCreate(ShopsActivity.java:61)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-30 14:10:28.975: E/WindowManager(12951):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 14:10:31.905: I/Process(12951): Sending signal. PID: 12951 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Always post your logcat/stacktrace, it helps solving the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UI modification only done in Ui thread.you are updating your ListView in `doInbackGround`() method which runs in a different thread..change your code like below..

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);               
        }
    });
```

or update listview in the `onPostExecute`() method of `AsynchTask` like..

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopsActivity.this, oslist,
                R.layout.listview_item_row, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                        TAG_ADDRESS_STRING }, new int[] { R.id.name_shop,
                        R.id.address_shop });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Ok I tried this but still got an exception, I will upload my log in a sec.

Comment: it will not give any exception..post your full logcat once..

Comment: place this  list.setAdapter(adapter); inside runonUiThread as i said above..and try..

Comment: Ok it is not giving exception, my mistake. But now my list view is blank.

Comment: that means in your SimpleAdapter getView() method is something wrong..check once..

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but I have to thank someone and kalyan you helped me a lot on this one! Thanks again. It's working now.

Comment: Thank you. This worked after I put the setAdapter inside the runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0):

put this code in onPostExecute

```
> HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>                     map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
>                     map.put(TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, address_string);
>                     oslist.add(map);
>                     list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
>                     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopsActivity.this, oslist,
>                             R.layout.listview_item_row,
>                             new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ADDRESS_STRING }, new int[] {
>                                     R.id.name_shop, R.id.address_shop});
>                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change or access ui elements in background thread. Error because of your listview setadapter method.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopsActivity.this, oslist,
         R.layout.listview_item_row, new String[] {TAG_NAME,TAG_ADDRESS_STRING}, 
         new int[] {
                       R.id.name_shop, R.id.address_shop
                   });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```